# React JS call function within another file in React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a function that's a separate React Component called `Modal.js` file that I would like to call the buttons that going to open Modal another React component - how can I achieve this?

`Modal.js`

```
class Modal extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loginOpened: false,
    signupOpened: false
  };

  openModal = modalType => () => {
    if (modalType === "login") {
      this.setState({
        loginOpened: true,
        signupOpened: false
      });
    } else if (modalType === "signup") {
      this.setState({
        loginOpened: false,
        signupOpened: true
      });
    }
  };

  closeModal = modalType => () => {
    if (modalType === "login") {
      this.setState({
        loginOpened: false
      });
    } else if (modalType === "signup") {
      this.setState({
        signupOpened: false
      });
    }
  };

    render() {
      return (
          <>
              <Modal isOpen={loginOpened} onRequestClose={this.closeModal("login")}>
                <h1>Login</h1>
                <button onClick={this.openModal("signup")}>Open Signup</button>
                <button onClick={this.closeModal("login")}>Close this modal</button>
              </Modal>

              <Modal isOpen={signupOpened} onRequestClose={this.closeModal("signup")}>
                <h1>Sign Up</h1>
                <button onClick={this.openModal("login")}>Open Login</button>
                <button onClick={this.closeModal("signup")}>Close this modal</button>
              </Modal>

              <button onClick={this.openModal("login")}>Open Login</button>
              <button onClick={this.openModal("signup")}>Open Signup</button>
          </>
      );
    }
}

  export default Modal;
```

I want to move this to `Navigation.js` So when those buttons are clicked the modal window will be called

```
<button onClick={this.openModal("login")}>Open Login</button>
<button onClick={this.openModal("signup")}>Open Signup</button>
```

Comment: Can you show us `Navigation.js` and how its component is related to `<Modal>` please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is over `Context`.

The files you should have are:

```
// ModalContext.js
import {createContext} from 'react'

export default createContext()
```

```
// Root.js -> This file should be on top of your application
import React from 'react'
import ModalContext from './ModalContext'

class ModalProvider extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loginOpened: false,
    signupOpened: false
  };

  openModal = modalType => () => {
    if (modalType === "login") {
      this.setState({
        loginOpened: true,
        signupOpened: false
      });
    } else if (modalType === "signup") {
      this.setState({
        loginOpened: false,
        signupOpened: true
      });
    }
  };

  closeModal = modalType => () => {
    if (modalType === "login") {
      this.setState({
        loginOpened: false
      });
    } else if (modalType === "signup") {
      this.setState({
        signupOpened: false
      });
    }
  };

  render(props) {
    return 
      <ModalContext.Provider value={{openModal: this.openModal, closeModal: this.closeModal}}>
        <Modal isOpen={loginOpened} onRequestClose={this.closeModal("login")}>
          <h1>Login</h1>
          <button onClick={this.openModal("signup")}>Open Signup</button>
          <button onClick={this.closeModal("login")}>Close this modal</button>
        </Modal>
        <Modal isOpen={signupOpened} onRequestClose={this.closeModal("signup")}>
           <h1>Sign Up</h1>
           <button onClick={this.openModal("login")}>Open Login</button>
           <button onClick={this.closeModal("signup")}>Close this modal</button>
        </Modal>
        {props.children}
      </ModalContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default
```

```
// Anywhere where you need to control your modals
import ModalContext from './ModalContext'

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  ...
  render(props) {
    return (
      <ModalContext.Consumer>
        {({openModal, closeModal}) => <button onClick={openModal("login")}>Open Login</button>}
      </ModalContext.Consumer>
    )
  }
}
```

You can check more on [Contexts here](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: When I read and setup everything way that your teaching me. I'm getting an error message saying that `TypeError: render is not a function` after adding the 3th code in my navbar.

Comment: I updated my response, probably you didn't put the render function on a React Component.

I recommend you to check functional components with the use of hooks. That's the new way.